# How to Convert Dictionary to String or StringBuffer in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to convert Dictionary to String for Regex pattern Match
but for this we need string or stringbuffer 
any Idea how to do it?

Answer (score 8):

In the `BuiltIn` library there is the standard keyword `Convert To String` that you can use for this:

```python
*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${dict}            Create Dictionary    a=1    b=2    c=3
    ${nested_dict}     Create Dictionary    first=${dict}    second=${dict}

    ${string}    Convert To String    ${dict}
    ${nested}    Convert To String    ${nested_dict}
```